# Calculate stable time step DG method for advection-diffusion

Tags: computational-physics, numerics, discontinuous-galerkin

For stable time steps for the RKDG method for transport equations we require that

$$
\Delta t \le \frac{\Delta x CFL}{(2k + 1)|\lambda|},
$$
where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of our conservation law and $k = 0, 1, \dots$.  For diffusion I believe we require that

$$
\Delta t \le \frac{\Delta x^{2}}{\nu},
$$
where $\nu$ is the diffffusion coefficient.  To calculate a stable time step I am doing the following,
$$
\Delta t \le \min \left\{\frac{\Delta x^{2}}{\nu},\frac{\Delta x CFL}{(2k + 1)|\lambda|}\right\}.
$$
It works reasonably well for $k = 1$ up to 160 elements.  For $k = 2$, it only produces stable time steps for up to 80 elements.  The solution does not blow up but I do not get the correct rate of convergence.  As such, I was curious if someone had a literature reference or could provide the correct expression on how to calculate stable time steps that would yield the correct rates of convergence.  For the time being I would like to stick with explicit RK methods for simplicity as I'm still learning DG.  As a side note, the CFL condition I'm choosing is quite small, i.e. $CFL = 0.05$ to $CFL = 0.01$.

Comment: What rate of convergence are you talking about here?

Comment: To measure the spatial accuracy of the DG method.  I get order 2 for P1, so thats fine.  But using P2 basis functions I do not get a rate of convergence of order 3 for very refined meshes.  I have dome some testing and how I calculate my DT makes a huge difference.  The only problem is the way I'm calculating it I feel is not correct as if it was, I would be getting the correct rate of convergence.  As a note, I start with 10 elements and keep doubling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you should consider:

Convection:

$$
\Delta t_C \le  CFL \cdot \alpha_{RK}(p) \cdot \frac{\Delta x}{(2k + 1)|\lambda|}.
$$

Diffusion:

$$
\Delta t_D \le  DFL \cdot \beta_{RK}(p) \cdot \frac{\Delta x^2}{(2k + 1)^2\nu}.
$$

Finally:

$$\Delta t = \text{min}(\Delta t_C,\Delta t_D).$$

Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scaling factors for different RK methods depending on the polynomial degree and the spatial operator.

Note that $CFL<=1$ and $DFL<=1$. Moreover these conditions do only hold for Cartesian meshes or to be more precise - for the one dimensional case. For unstructured meshes you also have to consider metric terms.

Comment: Thank you for the informative reply.  For the case of SSP RK methods (I'm using a 5th-order linear SSP), what would beta and alpha be?  For the diffusion term I am using the LDG with alternative fluxes (to achieve a compact stencil).  For the convection term I am using the Lax-Friedrichs scheme for the numerical flux.

Comment: This depends on the spatial operator (DG), the RK method and the physical system you are considering.

Comment: To be more precise: You have to calculate the discrete Eigenvalues of your system.

Comment: In terms of the spatial DG operator, I am merely using the original 1D formulation by Cockburn and Shu, i.e. the modal approach.  In terms of the physical problem, I am solving the linear advection-diffusion for simplicity.  I hope I'm making sense..

Comment: Generally the values ranging from $\pi $ to  $0.1$. But this is only a rude assumption.

Comment: The correct way would be to calculate the characteristic polynomial of your discrete system and plot a stability diagram in a complex plain.